# Can't increase variable

Tags: html, razor

I'm working on a navigation and for some reason, I can't increase a variable.

```
   <ul id="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="/" class="drop">Home</a>
            <div class="dropdown_2columns">
                <!-- Begin 2 columns container -->
                <div class="col_2">
                    <h2>Welcome !</h2>
                </div>
            </div><!-- End 2 columns container -->
        </li><!-- End Home Item -->
        @foreach (var mainNode in rootNode.Children())
        {
            int childCount = 1;
            int numChildren = mainNode.Children().Count();
            int num = 0;                              @*<-------------- Num variable*@
            <li>
                <a href="@mainNode.Url" class="drop">@mainNode.Name</a>
                <div id=main-@num class="dropdown_5columns"> @*<----------Using the variable here*@
                    <!-- Begin 2 columns container -->
                    <div class="col_5">
                        <h2>@mainNode.Name</h2>
                    </div>
                    @* note if you want ALL descendants change .Children to .Descendats*@
                    @foreach (var childNode in mainNode.Children())
                    {
                        // if first node or new set of three open the div and ul @: is used to stop razor trying to
                        // "balance" the tags
                        if (childCount == 1 || (double)childCount % 3 == 1)
                        {
                            @:<div class="col_1">
                                @:<ul>
                        }
                        <a href="@childNode.Url">@childNode.Name</a>

                        // close the div and list if this is either a multiple of 3 or the last one
                        if ((double)childCount % 3 == 0 || numChildren == childCount)
                        {
                            @:</ul>
                        @:</div>
                        }
                        childCount++;
                        num++;    @*< -----------Increasing the varable here*@
                    }
                </div>

            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

The problem is that the varable doesnt increase after looping. The div id is always `main-0` even after looping multiple times. Does anyone know the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Num" is placed inside the mainNode loop, so it's always set to 0.

You have to move the num variable outside the mainNode loop and it should work :-)